# Pandas Groupby with no aggregation for single result

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby, aggregation

I have a Dataframe in Pandas that shows percentage of men in a city/state. The dataframe `df` looks like the following (note this is not my actual usage/data but my datatypes are similar)

```
STATE      CITY        PERC_MEN
ALABAMA    ABBEVILLE   41.3%
ALABAMA    ADAMSVILLE  53.5%
....
WYOMING    WRIGHT      46.6%
```

Each State/percentage of men combo will have exactly 1 value returned.

How do I show the city/population values for a given state? My code looks like the following (I need the first line where I groupby `STATE` because I do other stuff with the data)

```
for state, state_df in df.groupby(by=['STATE']):
    print(state_df.groupby(by=['CITY'])['PERC_MEN'])
```

However this prints `<pandas.core.groupby.generic.SeriesGroupBy object at 0xXXXXXXX>`

Normally for groupby's I use an aggregate like `mean()` or `sum()` but is there a way to just return the value?

Comment: There must be a better way to do this, but you can use `state_df.groupby(by=['CITY'])['PERC_MEN'].apply(lambda x:  x)` to return the value as is.

Answer (score 1):

I wouldnt iterate dataframe.

Set index and slice

```
df=df.set_index(['STATE','CITY'])


df.xs(('ALABAMA', 'ABBEVILLE'), level=['STATE','CITY'])
```

or

```
df.loc[('ALABAMA', 'ABBEVILLE'),:]
```